# How to write text output into a file?

Tags: java, io

After referring to some of the questions on this site, I learnt that `BufferedWriter` can be used to write text content into a file. I used the following lines of code. But, I see no output is being written into the file. The file is empty.

**Edited**

> **Code Snippet:**

```
private void findPrimes(int min, int max) throws IOException {
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/hduser/prime.txt"));
            if (i == 1) {
                writer.write("1 is not a prime.");
                continue;
            }
            if (i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7) {
                writer.write(i + " is a prime");
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = 2; j <= 9; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                writer.write(i + " is a prime.");
            } else {
                writer.write(i + " is not a prime. Its factors are ");
                writer.newLine();
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of i? Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: and `if i == 0`? etc. etc.

Comment: Why are you closing your writer all the time? That should happen only when you're done, outside the loop. And you need to flush before you close.

Comment: Put only one `close()` in the end of your code. You should create only one `BufferedWriter` in the beginning of your method. See my answer.

Comment: @Mauren. Tried that too. Only one line is being printed to the file. I gave 1, 10000 as parameters to the method.

Comment: @Phoenix please note that default file writing behavior is truncating whenever you open a file. See my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides your `if` conditions, as far as I am concerned, `Writer` interfaces are not guaranteed to flush data to disk before you explicitly close them.

Try

```
writer.close()
```

when you are done writing your file and see whether this problem persists.

**EDIT:**

You should create your `BufferedWriter` only once, at the beginning of your method, since default file writing procedure consists of truncating previous file contents. Your code should look something like

```
private void findPrimes(int min, int max) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/hduser/prime.txt"));

    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        boolean isPrime = true;

        if (i == 1) {
            writer.write("1 is not a prime.");
            writer.flush();
            continue;
        }

        if (i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7) {
            writer.write(i + " is a prime");
            writer.flush();
            continue;
        }

        for (int j = 2; j <= 9; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isPrime) {
            writer.write(i + " is a prime.");
            writer.flush();
        } else {
            writer.write(i + " is not a prime. Its factors are ");
            findFactors(i);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a

```
writer.flush();
```

before calling

```
writer.close();
```

?

Comment: Yes. I tried. No use. Not all the content is being written to the file.

Comment: can you give some sample output and the used parameters?

Answer (score 0):

This will write to a file check it ..

```
 private static void findPrimes(int min, int max) throws IOException {

   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/home/hduser/prime.txt")));

for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
     if (i == 1) {
        writer.write("1 is not a prime.");
        continue;
    }
    if (i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7) {
        writer.write(i + " is a prime");

        continue;
    }
    for (int j = 2; j <= 9; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPrime) {

        writer.write(i + " is a prime.");
        writer.newLine();

    } else {
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write(i + " is not a prime.");

    }

}

writer.flush();
```

}